# Unable to ssh from the Docker host to a container

Tags: ssh, docker

I would like to `ssh` into a running docker container.  `sshd` is running inside the docker container. Also the host/container connectivity is showing some healthiness given I am able to run GUI apps and view the display on the host via  `xhost +`.

Here is the IP address info for the container: we see it has an IP address of  `172.17.0.2`:

[image]

And here is the `ssh daemon` info on that same container:

```
 netstat -an
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

But ssh to the container from the host is not working at all: it simply times out:

```
$ssh root@172.17.0.2
connect to host 172.17.0.2 port 22: Operation timed out
```

What else needs to be done for `ssh` from the host to the container to work?

Comment: Why do you need to SSH? Can't you just use `docker exec`?

Comment: I did find that soon after posting this question: but am still interested in the answer since it is useful for generic scripts that can be run in different scenarios as well as docker to docker communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there is a command line parameter

```
 -p hostPort:containerPort
```

So for my example:

```
 docker run -it -p 24:22 --name tfcv4 tensorflow-opencv
```